# Большой файл скачивается не полностью

Tags: c#, асинхронность, httpclient

Есть файл(*.rar) доступный по url. Файл размером больше 6Гб. Функция скачивания организована след образом. Но когда размер скачиваемого файла достигает к примеру 1.5 Гб(но всегда по разному), то скачивание прекращается без ошибок, но сам архив естественно распаковать не получается.

```
private async Task DownloadFileAsync(string uri, string source, CancellationToken ct)
{
    _logger.Info_DownLoadStarted(uri);
    using (var client = HttpClientExtensions.Create())
    {
        try
        {
            using (var response = await client.GetAsync(uri, HttpCompletionOption.ResponseHeadersRead, ct))
            using (Stream streamToReadFrom = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync())
            {
                using (Stream streamToWriteTo = File.Open(source, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await streamToReadFrom.CopyToAsync(streamToWriteTo, 4096, ct);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            _logger.Error_DownLoad(uri, exception.ToString());
            throw;
        }
    }
    _logger.Info_DownLoadComplete(uri);

}
```

Comment: Хм. Может, проблема на сервере? Код выглядит нормально. Посмотрите, скачиваются ли большие файлы с других серверов.

Comment: А `Info_DownLoadComplete` выполняется?

Comment: @VladD да, выполняется

Comment: @gregor с большим размером буфера пробовали?

Comment: @wardef нет не пробовал . Может ли скачка завершится втихую без ошибок в данном случае ?

Comment: @gregor ваших факторов я не знаю, но мне кажется, что увеличения буфера может помочь, если нет, то будем думать. Ну и банальный вопрос, а дебажить пробовали?

Comment: Может снаружи стоит таймаут и передаёт внутрь cancelationToken?

Comment: @Anxis точно нет